# Get Point3D relative to Mesh in WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have a pretty simple 3D scene that is roughly built up like this:

```
<Viewport3D>
  <ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
        <Model3DGroup x:Name="Group1">
          <GeometryModel3D x:Name="m1">...</GeometryModel3D>
        </Model3DGroup>
        <Model3DGroup x:Name="Group2">
          <GeometryModel3D x:Name="m2">...</GeometryModel3D>
        </Model3DGroup>
        <Model3DGroup x:Name="Group3">
          <GeometryModel3D x:Name="m3">...</GeometryModel3D>
        </Model3DGroup>
    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
  </ModelVisual3D>
</Viewport3D>
```

And basically each of the 3 GeometryModel3D's has its own Mesh, Transforms, etc...

When I do hit testing on the Viewport3D, all I ever get is the point in 3D space that I clicked when I hit something. What I really am after, is the point ON the mesh that I hit in 3D space (not a single Point on the mesh, but rather the Point3D).

The goal for me is to add a new Material to the clicked on Mesh at the exact point that the user clicks. And I cannot do that if I only have access to the Point3D relative to the Viewport3D (because of all the transforms on the meshes etc...)

An example might be that the m1 Geometry is a rectangle like shape, with some slight rotations and transformed up the Y axis so its at the top of the screen.

When I click on the VERY bottom of the mesh, I would like to get the X-Y (Z not needed here) point relative to the local coordinate space of that mesh...

I hope that all makes sense, and thanks for any help you can give

Mark

Comment: Matrix Inverse operation could probably help?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is actually two things:

1. Ray projection: given a hit-point on the 2D representation (i.e., the screen), cast a Ray from that point into your scene. This is alternatively called "Unproject", since it kind of relies on inverting the original screen transformation matrix and choosing some minimum and maximum "depth" values.
2. Ray/Mesh hit intersection: given a Ray and a Mesh, find where they meet. A slightly generalized variant is Ray/Sphere intersection [Ray-Sphere Intersection](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-7-intersecting-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection/)

Check out this guy's blog, he has all the info I think you'll need:
[Daniel Lehenbauer's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/danlehen/default.aspx)